# Add a second template field in section settings via plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, control-panel, settings

I would like to add a second default template field for each section's Site Settings, via plugin. Where would I look to see how to do this?

How would I access this value in my plugin's code? How would I parse the template path to use to render an entry?